# Hive partition by expression or template

Tags: java, templates, hadoop, hive, expression

I found a script of hive-ql like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dwd.o_p_data_reports
DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (partition_dt='${#date(0,0,-1):yyyyMMdd#}');

insert overwrite table dwd.o_p_data_reports partition (partition_dt = '${#date(0,0,-1):yyyyMMdd#}')
-- no changed
select 
 dwd.id
,dwd.title
,dwd.desc
,dwd.source
,dwd.source_url
,dwd.download_url
,dwd.cloud_url
,dwd.publish_date
,dwd.created_at
,dwd.updated_at
,dwd.last_fetched_at
,dwd.size
,dwd.cate
,dwd.author
,dwd.site
,dwd.page_num
,dwd.sectors
from 
(select * from dwd.o_p_data_reports where partition_dt = '${#date(0,0,-2):yyyyMMdd#}') dwd 
left join 
(select * from ods.o_p_data_reports where partition_dt = '${#date(0,0,-1):yyyyMMdd#}') ods  
on dwd.id = ods.id  
where ods.id is null
```

And there's something unusual, **`'${#date(0,0,-1):yyyyMMdd#}'`** seems like an expression, which will produce some certain value **before** executing the whole query script.

This script works well on a server, and `partition_dt` will be like `20200115`.
However, it will fail on my own computer from directly execution in hive shell, because `partition_dt` will only produce `$` in this case.

From what I know, `partition_dt = '${#date(0,0,-1):yyyyMMdd#}'` is:

1. not hive function call, since
2. not hive variable, since there're no variables set at the first line, and the format is wrong(which is `${foobar}`, not `${#foobar#}`)
3. not UDF, since there's no UDF import
4. not dynamic partition, because it will fail with the dynamic partition(using hive datetime function like `date_add()`) on the server but success with this one.

So what is `'${#date(0,0,-1):yyyyMMdd#}'`?

Comment: Check how the script is being executed. For example qubole can use some macros https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/using-macros.html. Maybe some other tool doing substitution

Comment: @leftjoin yes, now I believe this is some kind of macro, but I don't know what it is exactly.